Revit 2025 App Bundle migration causes "Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions.RevitServerUnauthorizedException" when saving model to ACC
Our group utilizes app bundles to automate project setup in ACC. We have been utilizing the same process for versions of Revit 2022-2024 with no problems. I have recently ran into issues when attempting to run an add-in that does this same process for 2025. My only change to the source code has been changing the environment to .NET8 and rebuilding dependencies.
The flow goes as such:

A user requests model creation for 2025 within a web app. Sending a request that includes a adsk3LeggedToken that contains a scope of code:all
The add-in downloads a .rte template, stored in ACC.
app.NewProjectDocument(template)
The result of the download is saved locally as a normal Revit model.
doc.SaveAs(path);
Where I get my error: I then attempt to save the model to the cloud
 doc.SaveAsCloudModel(accountID, projectID, folderID, modelName);

Upon attempting to save I get this error:
[] Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions.RevitServerUnauthorizedException: You don't have the workshared cloud model entitlement (BIM 360 Docs or Autodesk Docs) to perform the operation to this Document.
[] at Autodesk.Revit.DB.Document.SaveAsCloudModel(Guid accountId, Guid projectId, String folderId, String modelName)

as well as an error in the journal (very sorry its messy):
' 0:< Find mgmt endpoint of region GLOBAL : https://mgmt.skyscraper-staging.autodesk.com/api 
'C 28-Aug-2024 19:29:54.991;  DBG_INFO: Empty id token. Should check login status before using GetIdToken(): line 222 of F:\Ship\2025_px64\Source\Foundation\Utility\Managers\ManageSSOImpl.cpp. 
'C 28-Aug-2024 19:29:55.145;   0:< {"start_time":"2024-08-28T19:29:55.1190358Z","http_method":"GET","http_url":"https://mgmt.skyscraper-staging.autodesk.com/api/users/@me","http_request_headers":"{x-ads-correlation-id=<redacted>,x-ads-request-id=<redacted>,x-ads-ctx-user=<redacted>}","duration":124,"http_response_code":401,"http_response_headers":"{x-ads-correlation-id=<redacted>1}"} 
' 0:< ManagementClientInterface.GetUserAsync failed with exception:  
' 0:<   System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (HTTP response exception) 
' 0:<     Autodesk.Http.HttpResponseException: HTTP response exception 
' 0:< Entitlement Validation: Fault when trying to get entitlements. 

I have administrator access to the hub, the project, docs, and the folder I am trying to post to. I have also had another admin attempt the same.
The weird thing is that this EXACT code works for 2022-2024. The only difference (that I can see) being the version of.NET, its dependencies and the Revit engine. I am able to change the environment to .NET4.8 and specify the engine as Revit 2024 and it works as expected.
I am really hoping I am missing some permissions somewhere. Any help would be appreciated.
Update:
I have also tried creating a new project and folders, to ensure that the project was not dependent on an older version of Revit. I have also tried the same code dependent on .NET4.8 and running on the Revit 2025 engine and get the same error, so seems to be confined to the engine itself.

Hi Mason, we are working on this, looks there is an issue with Revit DA 2025 for RCW, I got the similar issue while opening the RCW.

this is an issue related to Revit Cloud Model in Design Automation cloud engine 2025, and it's fixed, could you please verify it now?

I can confirm that this is working now. Thank you!
